# How to set up Django for Fastpanel

Tags: django, apache, nginx, server, uwsgi

I used .htaccess

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler wsgi-script .py
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wsgi.py/$1 [QSA,PT,L]
```

for HestiaCP and wsgi.py

```
import os
import sys
 
sys.path.append('PATH_TO_PROJECT')
sys.path.append('PATH_TO_PACKAGES_PYTHON')
 
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project_name.settings')
 
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

and it worked but doesn't work in Fastpanel. How to be?

Answer (score 0):

```
apt install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
```

and read this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: Once you’ve got mod_wsgi installed and activated, edit your Apache server’s httpd.conf file and add the following.

`WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/mysite.com/mysite/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonHome /path/to/venv
WSGIPythonPath /path/to/mysite.com

<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/mysite>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>`